# Sublime text 3 (Error install Package Control)

Tags: sublime-text-3, package

Устанавливаю package control для sublime text 3. https://packagecontrol.io/installation по иструкции. Выбивает такую ошибку
[image: Error install package control]

---

> > > import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '2915d1851351e5ee549c20394736b442' + '8bc59f460fa1548d1514676163dafc88'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
> > >       186789
> > >       reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
> > >       reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
> > >       reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
> > >       reloading settings Packages/Package Control/Package Control.sublime-settings
> > >       reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
> > >       reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
> > >       Package Control: Installing 1 missing dependency
> > >       Package Control: Installed missing dependency bz2
> > >       Package Control: No updated packages
> > >       error: Package Control

1 missing dependency was just installed. Sublime Text should be restarted, otherwise one or more of the installed packages may not function properly.

Comment: Ну так вы перезапустили Sublime Text, как просит установщик? Уведомление говорит о том, что как раз была установлена недостающая зависимость.

Comment: ...и вообще это не ошибка.